# postgresql select minimum from a value pair of two columns

Tags: postgresql, select, distinct

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id | group | title | description | added | modified
---------------------------------------------------
1  |   1   |  ...  |     ...     |  ...  |   ...
2  |   1   |  ...  |     ...     |  ...  |   ...
3  |   2   |  ...  |     ...     |  ...  |   ...
4  |   2   |  ...  |     ...     |  ...  |   ...
5  |   3   |  ...  |     ...     |  ...  |   ...
```

Now I need to select the first row of every group value. I think using the DISTINCT keyword is kind of the right direction here. But using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT group FROM table;
```

obviously would return only the group values, but not the remaining fields:

```
group
-----
  1
  2
  3
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

What I'm looking for is - in regard to the above example - this kind of output:

```
id | group | title | description | added | modified
---------------------------------------------------
1  |   1   |  ...  |     ...     |  ...  |   ...
3  |   2   |  ...  |     ...     |  ...  |   ...
5  |   3   |  ...  |     ...     |  ...  |   ...
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please note that group is a reserved word.

Comment: Yeah I actually changed it to "member". My mistake!

Comment: I changed it to `zgroup` (to be pronounced with a German accent ;-)

Comment: Oddly enough I am german ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT mk.* FROM meuk mk
JOIN ( SELECT zgroup, MIN(id) AS id
        FROM meuk
        GROUP BY zgroup
        ) agg ON agg.id = mk.id
        ;
```

Or this one:

```
SELECT * FROM meuk mk
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  *
        FROM meuk nx
        WHERE nx.zgroup = mk.zgroup
        AND nx.id < mk.id
        )
        ;
```

Comment: Your second solution works like a charm. I can't really say that I understand your first solution though =\

Comment: Well is is a joined (aggregating) subquery, just like the `a` in Joachim's solution and the `tg` in collapsar's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like;

```
SELECT "id", "group", "title", "description", "added", "modified"
FROM (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY "group" ORDER BY "id") rn
  FROM Table1
) this_could_be_called_anything
WHERE rn=1;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/a43e6/1).

Comment: If you don't mind, could you elaborate what happens here? Especially what "a" does?

Comment: @tiiv `a` is just an alias for the sub-expression (one is required, you could call it anything) ROW_NUMBER() assigns a row number sequence (1..n) per partition (group), I just grab all rows that have a row number of 1, ie the first row in every group.

Answer (score 0):

try this One:

```
    select t.*
      from table t
inner join (
                select min(te.id)   id_pivot
                     , te.grp
                  from table te
              group by te.grp 
           ) tg
        on tg.id_pivot = t.id
         ;
```